# Junit Test Java

Tags: java, junit

Can someone please let me know how to write a Junit test for the if statement on the below method? Thanks

```
 public String preGame() {
 Scanner gameMode = new Scanner(System.in);      
   // Enforce player to select a valid game Option
   while (!gameMode.hasNext("1") && !gameMode.hasNext("2") && !gameMode.hasNext("3")){
    System.out.print(leftBorder + "Please enter a valid option (1,2,3)");
    gameMode.next();
   }

   String gameOption = gameMode.next();
   String optionMessage = null;
   if (gameOption.equals("1")) {
    optionMessage = "Human vs Human";
   } else if (gameOption.equals("2")) {
    optionMessage = "Human vs Computer";
   } else if (gameOption.equals("3")) {
    optionMessage = "Computer vs Computer";
   }
   System.out.println(leftBorder + "you've selected a game of " + optionMessage);
   return gameOption;
```

}

Comment: A unit test should be self contained and not depend on outside interaction, which you are currently doing through your `Scanner`. Consider refactorying so that the user input comes in from a method parameter.

Comment: What are you attempting to validate/test/assert?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis:  I was personally thinking that one could mock the `Scanner` instance, although that would mean it'd make the test easier if it was passed in.  It's *possible* to test this, but it's not *pretty*.

Comment: @Makoto That's an acceptable alternative. Code would still need to be refactored so that the `Scanner` _can_ be mocked. OP could make that the method parameter.

Comment: @Makoto this method returns the gameOption which can be 1,2,3. If there was a parameter such as gameOption than it would be easy to test. But as the method takes no parameters I got stuck on how to test it. Sorry if this is simple but I can't really understand the logic of this thing when it comes to testing it. The method was designed by someone else and I need to create the Junit test for it.

Comment: You should inform them that their design makes this method difficult to test appropriately, then reactor their code so that you could write the unit test for it.  One solution has already been bantered about by @SotiriosDelimanolis and myself above.

Comment: Substitute System.in to refer to appropriate test data sequences. This isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

While this is a bad design, as mentioned in comments above, the easiest way to test this code WITHOUT changing the source is to mock STDIN which is read by the `Scanner` in the method.  The only part to remember is to change STDIN back after the test.  This can be done with `@Before` and `@After`.

```
private InputStream realStdIn;


@Before
public void replaceStdIn(){
  realStdIn = System.in;      

}

@After
public void restoreStdIn(){
    //after test put STDIN back as System.in
    System.setIn(realStdIn);
}
```

Now our tests can set mock InputStream as our new STDIN

```
 @Test
 public void testGameMode1(){
     InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("1".getBytes());
     System.setIn(in);
     //now we can call preGame()
     assertEquals("Human vs Human".equals(preGame());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to dkatzel, if you want to test the output stream you can intercept that too. In stead of doing it in a `@Before` and `@After` you can also put the logic into a reusable [JUnit Rule](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/Rule.html). [Here's a rule I wrote](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/blob/57500cbe6a1bac4b333ba3e130b13dcf879318c8/cli/src/test/java/com/crawljax/test/util/CaptureSystemStreams.java) that helps me test the `System.out` classes in [this test](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/blob/57500cbe6a1bac4b333ba3e130b13dcf879318c8/cli/src/test/java/com/crawljax/cli/JarRunnerTest.java).